# How to store directory in variables

Tags: vb.net

I am using the following code to search for a specific file with .doc extension.
How can I get this info into a variable to be used later?

```
Dim di As New DirectoryInfo("d:\")
Dim files() As FileInfo = di.GetFiles("*.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already do have the info, in your files() array.

You can then use files() array to get a count of matches `files.Length`, or iterate through the matching files `foreach file as FileInfo in files {}`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue is, but the `files` variable in your code sample already contains this information.

This line:

```
Dim files() As FileInfo = di.GetFiles("*.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Gets the file information and assigns it to the `files()` array. This can now be used as it contains the information returned by the `GetFiles` method.

Comment: That is right.  But when I try to get the path by
msgbox(files(1))
It throws an error "Prompt Can not be converted into String"
I need to display the path of each file obtained in a message box
Thanks

Comment: @user415037 - Each item in the `files` array is a [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo_members.aspx) object, not a file path. You can do `msgbox(files(1).FullName))` to get the full path.

Comment: This works well ! Thank you
How Can I know how many elements are there in Files(), so I could run a loop.
Thnaks

Comment: @user415037 - Use `files.GetUpperBound(0)`. You need to learn about arrays and how to use them. Here is a useful link: http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/ssivkumar/ExploringArrays04212005060650AM/ExploringArrays.aspx

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've written, you've already got all the files `.doc` files in the `files()` array.

What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: That is right.  But when I try to get the path by
msgbox(files(1))
It throws an error "Prompt Can not be converted into String"
I need to display the path of each file obtained in a message box
Thanks